# Prove that if a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, then all of its subsequences converge.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that we do not know that every real Cauchy sequence converges. Since we know that if every subsequential limit of a sequence of real numbers converges to the same number, then the sequence itself converges to that number, let us try to get from a Cauchy sequence to this result.

Question: Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers. Show that every subsequential limit converges to the same real number.

I have been struggling to come up with a solid proof for this question. I keep getting stuck after applying the fact that a Cauchy sequence is bounded and therefore has a convergent subsequence. How in the world do I show that all the subsequences converge to the same number?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to mention that you mean convergence in the reals. Otherwise, not all Cauchy sequences converge. i.e. sequences of rationals.

Comment: Noted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Part $1$: Convergent subsequence

From the definition of [Cauchy Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_N-x_n|<1$. This then implies that for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$x_N-1<x_n<x_N+1$$

and therefore for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\min\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{N-1},x_N-1\}\leq x_n \leq \max\{x_1,x_2,...,x_{N-1},x_N+1\}$$

This implies that $x_n$ is a bounded sequence. Then by the [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) we may conclude that $x_n$ has at least one convergent subsequence. Let us denote this subsequence by $x_{n_k}$ and let its limit be

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k}=L$$

Part $2$: Entire sequence converges

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By definition, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\geq N$ implies $|x_{n_k}-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Additionally, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N_2\leq n\leq m$ implies $|x_n-x_m|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now, choose $N=\max\{n_{N_1},N_2\}$ and let $l$ be the smallest natural such that $n_l\geq N$ and $x_{n_l}$ is a member of the convergent subsequence. Then for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$\bigg||x_n-L|-|x_{n_l}-L|\bigg|\leq |(x_n-L)-(x_{n_l}-L)|=|x_n-x_{n_l}|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

(the first step in this equation is the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)). This then implies

$$0\leq  |x_n-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

(since $|x_{n_l}-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$). We conclude that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$$

Part 3: Convergent subsequences

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By defintion there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$. Now, let $x_{n_k}$ be any subsequence of $x_n$ and note that $n_k\geq k$. Therefore, for all $k\geq N$ we have $n_k\geq k\geq N$. This implies

$$|x_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon$$

We conclude

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}=L$$

Comment: The question asks to prove that the sequence converges because all of the subsequences converge to one real number.

Comment: The title is literally "Prove that if a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, then all of its subsequences converge" and further in the question you state "Question: Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers. Show that every subsequential limit converges to the same real number." That is what I haved proved. If you wanted a proof that did not go through proving the limit of the sequence in general existed, then you should state that

Comment: If you read the rest of the question, it specifies what is needed to go about answering the question properly.

Comment: "I keep getting stuck after applying the fact that a Cauchy sequence is bounded and therefore has a convergent subsequence. How in the world do I show that all the subsequences converge to the same number?" I took your work from there (the sequence is bounded) and then showed how to prove that every subsequence converges to the same number. Nowhere in your question did you state that you did not want to prove that the limit of the sequence existed in general before proving that every subsequence converges to the same number. Edit your question if that is something you want.

Comment: I will edit since there is clearly confusion, thank you for your time!